# Android ColorSpannot working if same text exists

Tags: android, textview, html

I have used following code to set color to a text in Text view.It works fine excepts if same text contains 2 or more times.That is if the text contains" @abc @abc" first @abc is displayed only in red color.Please help me.

```
 SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(Title);
                    final String[] str_array = Title.split(" ");

                    for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {


                        if (str_array[i].startsWith("@")) {

                            ss.setSpan(
                                    new ForegroundColorSpan(mcontext.getResources()
                                            .getColor(R.color.red)),
                                    Title.indexOf(str_array[i]),
                                    Title.indexOf(str_array[i])
                                            + (str_array[i].length()),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `String.indexOf()` method which returns:

> `indexOf(String)`: searches in this string for the first index of the specified string.

Therefore when you pass in `@abc @abc` it will always return `0` and will not apply the span to the second substring.

To solve this, you should use `indexOf(string, offset)` where you specify the offset. See the following code:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(Title);
final String[] str_array = Title.split(" ");

int lastOffset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    if (str_array[i].startsWith("@")) {
        int startPosition = Title.indexOf(str_array[i], lastOffset);
        int endPosition = startPosition + (str_array[i].length());
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                startPosition, endPosition,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        lastOffset = endPosition;
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Everytime you apply a span to a string, update the value of `lastOffset` so that the `indexOf(string, offset)` will return the next `substring`  instead of always returning the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only to set colors to your text you could use the following method:

```
Html.fromHtml()
```

and pass in necessary html tags.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#145A14\">text</font>"));
```

Comment: I have to set click on text if it stars with #

Answer (score 0):

This should work, make sure to add check for index out of bound errors in case String is just @a:

```
String Title = "@abs @abc";
int length = "@abc".length();
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(Title); 
int start = Title.indexOf("@", 0);
while (start != -1) {
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(mcontext.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.red)), start, start + length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    start = Title.indexOf("@", start + 1);
}
```